# Sqlite in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Hey guys I am trying to select my favorite person from the table by using their first name and then print out their first and middle name.I am also trying to make sure to parameterize the query. When I try to run the code it says KeyError: 'first_name' in my for loop of the assignmentRecords towards the bottom. Is even a step in the right direction or totally wrong?

```
# =============#
#    imports   #
# =============#
import sqlite3 #for working with sqlite version 3 databases

# ===============#
#    constants   #
# ===============#
SQL_FILE = "assignment_6.01-JonathanMaldonado.db"
SQL_CREATE_TABLE = """
CREATE TABLE person
(
  person_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name TEXT,
  middle_name TEXT,
  age TEXT,
  favorite_thing TEXT
)"""
SQL_DELETE_ASSIGNMENT = """
DELETE FROM person
WHERE person_id = ?
"""
SQL_INSERT_ASSIGNMENT = """
INSERT INTO person
  (first_name,middle_name,age,favorite_thing)
VALUES
  (?,?,?,?)
"""
SQL_SELECT_ASSIGNMENTS = """
SELECT
  person_id,
  first_name,
  middle_name,
  age,
  favorite_thing
FROM person
"""
SQL_UPDATE_ASSIGNMENT = """
UPDATE person
SET age = ?
WHERE person_id = ?
"""
# ===============#
#    functions   #
# ===============#
def createPersonTable(dbConnection):
  """ creates an assignment database table """

  #fill in the function to create the table
  #the SQL statement is provided as a constant
  dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
  dbCursor.execute(SQL_CREATE_TABLE)
  dbCursor.close()

def deleteAssignmentByID(dbConnection,AGE):
  """ deletes assignment records by their ID """

  #fill in the function to delete a record from the assignment table
  #the SQL statement is provided as a constant
  #be sure to parameterize as needed and check that 1 record was deleted
  dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
  arguments = [
      AGE,
  ]
  dbCursor.execute(SQL_DELETE_ASSIGNMENT,arguments)

  #make sure the record was deleted successfully
  numberOfRecordsInserted = dbCursor.rowcount
  if(numberOfRecordsInserted != 1):
    errorMessage = "{} records were inserted when there should have been 1"
    raise RuntimeError(errorMessage.format(numberOfRecordsInserted))

  #close the cursor
  dbCursor.close()

def insertAssignment(dbConnection,person):
  """ inserts assignment records one at a time """

  #fill in the function to insert a record
  #the SQL statement is provided as a constant
  #be sure to parameterize as needed and check that 1 record was inserted
  dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
  arguments = [
      person["first_name"],
      person["middle_name"],
      person["age"],
      person["favorite_thing"],
  ]
  dbCursor.execute(SQL_INSERT_ASSIGNMENT,arguments)

  #make sure the record was inserted successfully
  numberOfRecordsInserted = dbCursor.rowcount
  if(numberOfRecordsInserted != 1):
    errorMessage = "{} records were inserted when there should have been 1"
    raise RuntimeError(errorMessage.format(numberOfRecordsInserted))

  #close the cursor
  dbCursor.close()


def selectAllAssignments(dbConnection):
  """ returns a list of all assignment records """

  #fill in the function to return a list of assignment records
  #the SQL statement is provided as a constant
  dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
  dbCursor.execute(SQL_SELECT_ASSIGNMENTS)

  #build list of assignment records
  persons = []
  for record in dbCursor:
    person = {
        "person_id": record[0],
        " first_name": record[1],
        "middle_name": record[2],
        "age": record[3],
        "favorite_thing": record[4]

    }
    persons.append(person)

  #close the cursor and return the list
  dbCursor.close()
  return persons

# ==========#
#    main   #
# ==========#
def main():
  """ main method """

  #connect to the database using the file name provided as a constant
  dbConnection = sqlite3.connect(SQL_FILE)

  #dropping table in case you need to re-run this multiple times
  #no need to change this part
  dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
  try:
    dbCursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person")
  except Exception as e:
    dbConnection.close()
    raise #stop the rest of the script


  #create the assignment table
  #use the createAssignmentTable function and wrap in an appropriate try block
  try:
    createPersonTable(dbConnection)
  except Exception as e:
    #close the connection and stop
    dbConnection.close()
    raise #stop the rest of the script


  #loop through the following assignment records and insert them
  #use the insertAssignment function and wrap in an appropriate try block
  persons = [
      {
          "first_name": "Demi",
          "middle_name": "Rose",
          "age": "22",
          "favorite_thing": "Cute and funny",

      },
      {
          "first_name": "Esmeralda",
          "middle_name": "Arciga",
          "age": "48",
          "favorite_thing": "Lovly Mother",
      },
      {
          "first_name": "Dead",
          "middle_name": "Pool",
          "age": "32",
          "favorite_thing": "Superhero",
      }
  ]
  for person in persons:
    try:
      insertAssignment(dbConnection,person)
    except Exception as e:
      #roll back the transaction and stop
      dbConnection.rollback()
      dbConnection.close()
      raise #stop the rest of the script
    else:
      #commit the transaction
      dbConnection.commit()

  #select all of the assignment records and store in a variable
  #use the selectAllAssignments function and wrap in an appropriate try block
  try:
    assignmentRecords = selectAllAssignments(dbConnection)
  except Exception as e:
    #roll back the transaction and stop
    dbConnection.rollback()
    dbConnection.close()
    raise #stop the rest of the script
  else:
    pass #no need to commit since it was just a select

  #loop through the assignment records
  #print the title and due date of each and then delete that record
  #use the deleteAssignmentByID function and wrap in an appropriate try block
  for person in assignmentRecords:
    try:
      print("{} {} is {} old and {}".format(person["first_name"],person["middle_name"],person["age"],person["favorite_thing"]))
      deleteAssignmentByID(dbConnection,person["person_id"])
    except Exception as e:
      #roll back the transaction and stop
      dbConnection.rollback()
      dbConnection.close()
      raise #stop the rest of the script
    else:
      #commit the transaction
      dbConnection.commit()

  #close the database connection
  dbConnection.close()

# kick off main
if(__name__ == "__main__"):
  main()
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message as it isn't clear where exactly the problem is occurring.

Comment: What is line 204?

Comment: Looks like a typo here `" first_name": record[1],`. person has no key `"first_name"` but it does have a key `" first_name"`. There's an extra space